# Mongoose switch collections dynamically similar to database using useDb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to figure out a way to dynamically switch to different collections, or create one if one doesnt exist using the same schema. I am using Mongoose for my project. I know that it is possible to do this for databases using [useDb](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#connection_Connection-useDb) in Mongoose, but wondering if it is possible to do this for collections also.

At the moment, my model is something like

```
const dbModel = mongoose.model(
    config.mongo.DATABASE_NAME,
    new mongoose.Schema(
    ...
```

And I am making my connection using

```
mongoose.connect(dbUrl, {
    useNewUrlParser  : true,
    useFindAndModify : false
});
```

What I am trying to do is convert `config.mongo.DATABASE_NAME` to be user controlable using a POST request, and switch to different collections. I can change the value of `config.mongo.DATABASE_NAME` easily, but at the moment, that doesnt make a difference because it is at runtime.

I am also very open to a different approach on how to use the same existing model to create different collections by the end user.

Comment: Why not create the `model` at run time (or rather dynamically) & with predefined `schemas` and use that.  `.model('ModelName', Schema, 'collectionName')` takes third param as collection that can be passed dynamically. Looking at the example `schema` can be dynamic as well

Comment: @ambianBeing i had tried that before posting here. The issue is that because the mongoose instance has already started, changing the third param doesnt really have any effect on the app. The app still points to the old collection name it defaults to.

Comment: I may be missing something out here. Have a look at this [link](https://imgur.com/a/COePXYE). Tried to do what I mentioned with 2 different `collections` and `schema` with same `mongoose instance` mimicking `save()`. Works fine!

Comment: I think the reason why I cannot replicate your behavior is because my mongoose connection is part of an express app, and because the app is already running, it doesnt switch to a different collection. So lets say my db name is set in `let config.dbname = firstdb`, if i change that to seconddb using a post request, and then run `.save()`, it still saves to `firstdb`

Comment: I get it now. Since your `db` itself is changing you can't really do anything with a `collection` of different `db`. `mongoose.connect` does what you asserted. At best every time you'll need to use `mongoose.createConnection()` to switch `db` and create your models from that. **NOTE: `mongoose` instance will still be pointing to original connected db.**